# Compare and remove from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've got a multidimensional array as follows:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "117"
    ["promotiontype_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["groupa_id"]=>
    string(3) "390"
    ["groupb_id"]=>
    string(3) "390"
    ["varx"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["vary"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["varz"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totaldiscount"]=>
    float(6.5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "117"
    ["promotiontype_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["groupa_id"]=>
    string(3) "390"
    ["groupb_id"]=>
    string(3) "390"
    ["varx"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["vary"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["varz"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totaldiscount"]=>
    float(7.0)
  }
}
```

So, as you'll see, the first array has a "totaldiscount" of 6.5, the second has 7.0.

Essentially, I need to remove the array that contains the lowest value, so in this instance, it would be array [0] that gets removed as 6.5 has the lowest "totaldiscount". The array could contain more than 2 sub arrays.

I assume it's something to do with foreaching through, but my brain is going in to meltdown with this one!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can sort the array by totaldiscount asc and remove the first entry

Answer (score 0):

I am going to divide your question in 2 parts:

> How to find the lowest value of x?

```
function lowestX($array){
   $lowest = 999;
   for($array as $var){
      if($lowest > $var["totaldiscount"]){
         $lowest = $var["totaldiscount"];
      }
   }
}
```

> How do I remove a value from an array?

Use [unsset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) or [function.array-splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the arrays by "totaldiscount"

Then get the lowest "totaldiscount" value from the sorted arrays.

Then you can loop the sorted arrays (in case there are multiple "totaldiscount" values which have the same lowest value) and unset the array(s) which contains the `$lowestTotaldiscount` by using the array key.

For example:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return ($a["totaldiscount"] < $b["totaldiscount"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arrays, "cmp");

$lowestTotaldiscount = $arrays[0]["totaldiscount"];

foreach($arrays as $key => $array) {
    if ($array["totaldiscount"] === $lowestTotaldiscount) {
        unset($arrays[$key]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XCGEI)

Answer (score 0):

here is solution of your problem .Simply use  array_multisort & unset as given below .
`

```
$yourArray = array(
    array(
    "id"=>"117",
    "promotiontype_id"=>"1",
    "groupa_id"=>"390",
    "groupb_id"=> "390",
    "varx"=>"2",
    "vary"=>"1",
    "varz"=> "",
    "totaldiscount"=>8.5,
   ),
  array (
    "id"=> "117",
    "promotiontype_id"=>"1",
    "groupa_id"=>"390",
    "groupb_id"=>"390",
    "varx"=>"2",
    "vary"=>"1",
    "varz"=>"",
    "totaldiscount"=>7.0,
   ),
   array (
        "id"=> "117",
        "promotiontype_id"=>"1",
        "groupa_id"=>"390",
        "groupb_id"=>"390",
        "varx"=>"2",
        "vary"=>"1",
        "varz"=>"",
        "totaldiscount"=>9.0,   )
);
$discount = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $row)
{
    $discount[$key] = $row['totaldiscount'];
}
array_multisort($discount, SORT_ASC, $yourArray);
unset($yourArray[0]);
print"<pre>";
print_r($yourArray);`
```